# Linq join condition with multipe data from two table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

i have three table.
Table A

```
ID_A  data_A
1        a
2        b
```

Table B

```
ID_B  data_B ID_A
1      2      1
2      3      2
```

Table c

```
ID_C   data_C   ID_A   ID_B
1      1         1        1
```

my linq query

```
var data = (from a in _db.Table_A

join b in db.Table_B
on a.ID_A equals b.ID_A

join c in _db.Table_C
on new { ID_A = a.ID_A, ID_B = b.ID_B} equals new { ID_A = c.ID_A, ID_B = c.ID_B }

select a)
```

the join is showing error(**the type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the cal to join**) at joining table_C.
I want both table_A and Table_B id in join condition of Table_C join

Comment: Look at the post and try to answer your own question. Could you? There are no classes, not data types, just some names and values. This is far from [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query should be like

```
var data = (from a in _db.Table_A    
            join b in _db.Table_B on a.ID_A equals b.ID_A    
            join c in _db.Table_C on new { a.ID_A,b.ID_B} equals new { c.ID_A,c.ID_B }    
            select a)
```

here a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YpRaBD) in case if there is no `nullable` value in the table C

in case if one of the fields in `table_C` was `nullable` then, here a workaround to solve the issue

```
var data = (from a in _db.Table_A()    
            join b in _db.Table_B() on a.ID_A equals b.ID_A    
            join c in _db.Table_C() on new { m=a.ID_A,n=(int?)b.ID_B} equals new { m=c.ID_A,n=c.ID_B }    
        select a);
```

a working [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IkbWF6)

hope it will help you

Comment: error - the type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the cal to join

Comment: as you can see, based on the details you mentioned in your question, the answer works 100%, now returning back to your real work, it seems that you have some fields with different types like for example: `a.ID_A` was `long` and `b.ID_A` was `int` in this case you need to use `(int)` near the field with long data type, kindly confirm if you have such case or not

Comment: yeah in Table_C ID_B is nullable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123316/discussion-between-hadi-hassan-and-anand).